# Double linked list prepend element by ref in C

Tags: c, list, data-structures, linked-list

I try to write double linked list in C.

This is my implementation:

```
   typedef struct
    {
        void* value;
        struct Dlist* prev;
        struct Dlist* next;
    } Dlist;

    Dlist* createDlist()
    {
      Dlist* newList = (Dlist*)malloc (sizeof(Dlist));
      newList->value = NULL;
      newList->next = NULL;
      newList->prev = NULL;
      return newList;
    }

    /*
     * Get last element from Dlist
     */
    Dlist* getLast(Dlist* list)
    {
      if (list)
      {
          while(list->next)
            list = (Dlist*)list->next;
      }
      return list;
    }

    /*
     * add element to list at start
     */
    Dlist* addItemAtStart(Dlist* list, Pair* value)
    {
      Dlist* newList = NULL;
      Dlist* last = NULL;

      newList = createDlist ();
      newList->value = value;

      if (list)
      {
         last = getLast(list);
         last->next = newList;
         newList->prev = last;

         return list;
      }
      else
        return newList;
    }
```

Now, when i try to add element to my list, i need assign a new value every time:

```
list = addItemAtStart(list, "Hello");
```

But i want only

```
addItemAtStart(list, "Hello");
```

Without `list =` How can i make so that list will change without assign?

**p.s.** I get segfaut with `Dlist* addItemAtStart(Dlist **list, void* value)`

I try to insert so:

```
  Dlist **list = NULL;
  addItemAtStart(&list, "Hello");
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have to think about what your global "list"  object is. What you defined is really more of a "list node" rather than the list itself. How do you handle the list itself?

Comment: also, if you have a list object you can store a pointer to the last list node so you don't have to iterate to find it.

Answer (score 2):

If you handle the list by pointing to its first element, maybe you should use double indirection:

```
void addItemAtStart(Dlist** plist, Pair* value)
{
    // replace all list with *plist
}

addItemAtStart(&list, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your function to accept a pointer to a pointer to a List:

```
 Dlist* addItemAtStart(Dlist** list, Pair* value)
```

Just make sure you add another level of indirection inside of `addItemAtStart` when using `list`.

The function can be called using

```
addItemAtStart(&list, "Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

Give reference of the head node to insert node at start.

```
Dlist* addItemAtStart(Dlist** list, Pair* value)
    {
      Dlist* newList = NULL;
      Dlist* last = NULL;

      newList = createDlist();
      newList->value = value;

      if (list)
  {
     last = getLast(*list);
     last->next = newList;
     newList->prev = last;


  }
  else
    *list = newList
```

Answer (score 0):

for achieving that, you need to create a static linked list node pointer.
make sure that the atitematstart method updates that node.

Comment: That limits you to one list at a time, which is somewhat unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using a global list will solve your problem. In the function, assign the value to the list object. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code with some corrections and inclusions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    void* value;
    struct node *prev, *next;
};
/*This Function is Unnecessary
struct node * createList(){
    struct node *newNode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if (newNode==NULL) return NULL;

    newNode->value = NULL;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
          
    return newNode;
}
*/
/*
 *This Function is also Unnecessary
 *Get last element from Dlist
struct node* getLast(struct node* node){
    if (node==NULL) return NULL;

        while (node->next!=NULL) node=node->next;
    
        return node; 
}
*/
/*
*Description: add element to list at start
*
*Return Values:
*0:Failed
*1:Succeeded
*/
int addItemAtStart(struct node **head, void *value){
    struct node *newNode=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    /*Sometimes malloc can't allocate memory and returns NULL so you have to check it and if malloc couldn't allocate memory you have to exit the function*/
    if (newNode==NULL) return 0;
    
    newNode->value=value;
    newNode->prev=NULL;
    newNode->next=*head;

    if (*head!=NULL) (*head)->prev=newNode;
    *head=newNode;

    return 1;
}

int main(){
    struct node *list=NULL;
    
    addItemAtStart(&list, "apple");
    addItemAtStart(&list, "lemon");
    addItemAtStart(&list, "orange");
    addItemAtStart(&list, "peach");
    
    return 0;
}
```